# How to merge two dataframes based on a date condition from two different date columns in each dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have two Dataframes in the form:

**Dataframe(df1):**

| P_CLIENT_ID | P_DATE_ENCOUNTER |
| --- | --- |
| 25835 | 2016-12-21 |
| 25835 | 2017-02-21 |
| 25835 | 2017-04-25 |
| 25835 | 2017-06-21 |
| 25835 | 2017-09-04 |
| 25835 | 2018-01-08 |
| 25835 | 2018-04-03 |

**Dataframe(df2):**

| R_CLIENT_ID | R_DATE_TESTED | R_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25835 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 25835 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 25835 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |

I want to merge df2 onto df1 (main table) with the join key being `P_CLIENT_ID` and `R_CLIENT_ID` appending the most recent `R_DATE_TESTED` and `R_RESULT`

**First Condition:**
If `R_DATE_TESTED > P_DATE_ENCOUNTER` then nullify the `R_DATE_TESTED, R_RESULT` fields.

**Second Condition:**
If `R_DATE_TESTED < P_DATE_ENCOUNTER` then appned the most recent `R_DATE_TESTED, R_RESULT` fields to the dataframe with the final results as:

The result from logic should be as below:

| P_CLIENT_ID | R_CLIENT_ID | P_DATE_ENCOUNTER | R_DATE_TESTED | R_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | NaN | NaN |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | NaN | NaN |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |

Note: The actual dataset is quite large: df1 ~ 700000 rows and df2 ~ 125000 rows

**Code attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'P_CLIENT_D': ['25835','25835','25835','25835','25835','25835','25835'],
                    'P_DATE_ENCOUNTER': ['2016-12-21','2017-02-21','2017-04-25','2017-06-21','2017-09-04','2018-01-08','2018-04-03']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'R_CLIENT_ID': ['25835','25835','25835','25835','25835','25835','25835'],
                    'R_DATE_TESTED': ['2017-03-07','2017-08-03','2018-03-23','2019-06-28','2019-08-19','2020-04-20','2021-06-03'],
                   'R_RESULT':[20,20,20,20,42,40,20]})

df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['P_CLIENT_D'], right_on = ['R_CLIENT_ID'],  how='left')

df_merged = df_merged.drop_duplicates(subset=['P_CLIENT_D', 'P_DATE_ENCOUNTER'], keep='last')

df_merged['FLAG_LAB_AFTER_VISIT'] = 0
df_merged.loc[df_merged.R_DATE_TESTED >= df_merged.P_DATE_ENCOUNTER,'FLAG_LAB_AFTER_VISIT']=1
print(df_merged['FLAG_LAB_AFTER_VISIT'].sum(), 'future labs set to null')

#now the rows with flags - set all lab fields to null
df_merged.loc[df_merged['FLAG_LAB_AFTER_VISIT']==1, df2.columns] = np.nan
```

Comment: This is not a very hard task, you will most likely get help if you take your time to show what you have tried, and provide code to replicate these example tables so that it is easy for folks to get some test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
>>> pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                  df2, 
                  left_on="P_DATE_ENCOUNTER", 
                  right_on="R_DATE_TESTED", 
                  left_by="P_CLIENT_ID", 
                  right_by="R_CLIENT_ID")

   P_CLIENT_ID P_DATE_ENCOUNTER  R_CLIENT_ID R_DATE_TESTED  R_RESULT
0        25835       2016-12-21          NaN           NaT       NaN
1        25835       2017-02-21          NaN           NaT       NaN
2        25835       2017-04-25      25835.0    2017-03-07      20.0
3        25835       2017-06-21      25835.0    2017-03-07      20.0
4        25835       2017-09-04      25835.0    2017-08-03      20.0
5        25835       2018-01-08      25835.0    2017-08-03      20.0
6        25835       2018-04-03      25835.0    2018-03-23      20.0
```